# How do I have it so that sprites in a group all spawn in random locations only once in the draw function?

Tags: random, position, sprite, draw, p5.js

I want to have it in my code such that all of the sprites in a group variable spawn in different locations once in the draw function. The problem I am currently having is that since the draw function constantly repeats, all of the sprites are constantly changing positions due to this; and as you can imagine, they are rapidly moving all across the screen.

```
  drawSprites(toppingsGroup);
  for (var i = 0; i < toppingsGroup.length; i++) {
     toppingsGroup[i].position.x = 600;
     toppingsGroup[i].position.y = random(height);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Move the random position code to the `setup()` function
2. Wrap the random position code in an if block such that it only runs once

Option #1 is trivial, but here is an example of option #2

```js
let groupPositioned = false;

function draw() {
  if (!groupPositioned) {
    for (var i = 0; i < toppingsGroup.length; i++) {
     toppingsGroup[i].position.x = 600;
     toppingsGroup[i].position.y = random(height);
    }
    groupPositioned = true;
  }

  drawSprites(toppingsGroup); 
}
```